# Recursive map for tree-list structure in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a tree structure lists in R (lists of lists of arbitrary depth). This was formed by taking a multidimensional array in R and using the function `array_tree` from the purrr package. I would like to apply a function to tips of the tree (e.g., a recursive map) without having to flatten the structure.

How can I do this?

Comment: No comment on the vote down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize that actually the `at_depth` and `vec_depth` functions are exactly what I am looking for.

```
at_depth(a, vec_depth(a))
```